# Stop NTP from listening on ports.

Tags: ntpd

On my server, the time should be fetched. It should no be provided to other servers. I would call this a client.

But it seams that NTP is by default running in server mode, since it is opening ports and listening (waiting from packages).

```
foohost:~ # netstat -tulpen| grep ntp
udp        0      0 10.172.19.11:123        0.0.0.0:*                           0          17756202   28508/ntpd          
udp        0      0 30.251.32.11:123        0.0.0.0:*                           0          17756200   28508/ntpd          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           0          17756198   28508/ntpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           0          17756194   28508/ntpd          
udp        0      0 fe80::250:56ff:fe30:123 :::*                                0          17756206   28508/ntpd          
udp        0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                0          17756204   28508/ntpd          
udp        0      0 :::123                  :::*                                0          17756191   28508/ntpd
```

How to stop ntp opening ports and listening?

Linux version: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3

NTPD version: ntp-4.2.8p10-63.3.x86_64

Comment: Not realy understand why using `ntpd` in ought to get time only. You can use `ntpdate` and put it in the cron.

Comment: Thank you for down-voting this question. I know this question is annoying and was asked before. But the real problem is the missing sane default value oft ntpd.

Answer (score 2):

This is just basic NTPd configuration as discussed in many posts here like

[How to prevent ntpd to listen on 0.0.0.0:123?](https://serverfault.com/questions/475635/how-to-prevent-ntpd-to-listen-on-0-0-0-0123)

[Does NTPd have to listen on an interface or address for updating the server time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/236883/does-ntpd-have-to-listen-on-an-interface-or-address-for-updating-the-server-time?rq=1)

etc.

If you only want to set the server's time, use ntpd (configured to your liking) [in combination with sntp](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate).